# Validator error message changes TextFormField's height

Tags: flutter, dart

When the error message shows up, it reduces the height of the `TextFormField`. If I understood correctly, that's because the height of the error message is taking into account in the height specified.

Here's a screen before :

[image: before]

and after :

[image: after]

Tried to put `conterText: ' '` to the BoxDecoration (as I've seen on another topic) but it didn't help.

An idea ?

EDIT : OMG completly forgot to put the code, here it is :

```dart
 return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: 40.0,
            child: _createTextFormField(loginEmailController, Icons.alternate_email, "Email Adress", false, TextInputType.emailAddress),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 40.0,
            child: _createTextFormField(loginPasswordController, Icons.lock, "Password", true, TextInputType.text),
          ),

          SizedBox(
            width: double.infinity,
            child: loginButton
          )
        ],
      ),
    );

  }

  Widget _createTextFormField(TextEditingController controller, IconData icon, String hintText, bool obscureText, TextInputType inputType){
      return TextFormField(
        keyboardType: inputType,
        controller: controller,
        obscureText: obscureText,
        /* style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 15.0,
        ), */
        decoration: InputDecoration(
         /*  contentPadding:
              EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0, horizontal: 8.0), */
          border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
          icon: Icon(
            icon,
            color: Colors.black,
            size: 22.0,
          ),
          //hintText: hintText,
          labelText: hintText,
        ),
        validator: (value) {
          if (value.isEmpty) {
            return 'Enter some text';
          }
          return null;
        },
      );
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: Most be because your error text is trying to fit into a specific container. Show your code so we can help you easily.

Comment: You should post your code..

Answer (score 40, accepted):

In your Code - you need to comment out the `40` height given to each container.

```
Container(
             // height: 40.0,
              child: _createTextFormField(
                  loginEmailController,
                  Icons.alternate_email,
                  "Email Adress",
                  false,
                  TextInputType.emailAddress),
            ),
            Container(
            //  height: 40.0,
              child: _createTextFormField(loginPasswordController, Icons.lock,
                  "Password", true, TextInputType.text),
            ),
```

and then in your - `TextFormField` in `InputDecoration`, you can alter these value as per your liking.

```
  contentPadding:
      EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 10.0),
```

Comment: Yes, but what if you want the form field to be smaller, I find the default size too big, and the only way I have found to make it smaller is by using a container. The padding doesn't change the height of the field. So still a problem, for me at least.

Comment: Use `isDense: true`

Answer (score 14):

Instead of using a fixed height container to wrap the textFormField, You can try to put a space in the helper text so it will keep the height of the field constant while only displaying when there is an error.

```dart
return TextFormField(
   // ...
   decoration: InputDecoration(
     // ...
     helperText: " ",
     helperStyle: <Your errorStyle>,
   )
```

According to [Flutter Doc](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/forms/validation) :

> To create a field whose height is fixed regardless of whether or not an error is displayed, either wrap the TextFormField in a fixed height parent like SizedBox, or set the InputDecoration.helperText parameter to a space.

Comment: Should consider this as the question answer.

Comment: Nice answer. Even an empty text worked, you don't need a space

Answer (score 13):

Above solutions did not work for me however I have figured out a very simple solution to avoid the above issue

```
TextFormField(
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      **errorStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 0.01),**
      errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(borderRadius),
        borderSide: const BorderSide(
          color: AppColor.neonRed,
          width: LayoutConstants.dimen_1,
          style: BorderStyle.solid,
        ),
      ),
   );
```

Catch in the above solution is that we are setting the size of the error message to 0.01 so as a result it don't show up.

Additionally we can have custom border for the error.

Note : Setting the Text size to 0 is not working as it don't consider the text size and textFormField widget gets shrinked.

Comment: errorStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 0.01) ---> You saved my day, thank u

Comment: You just saved my day mate. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that we are not able to see your code so it might be challenging to assist you but I will do everything from scratch. You can firstly create the authentication class in one dart file

```
class AuthBloc{
   StreamController _passController = new StreamController();
   Stream get passStream => _passController.stream;
   bool isValid(String pass){
       _passController.sink.add("");
       if(pass == null || pass.length < 6){
         _passController.sink.addError("Password is too short");
         return false;
       }
       else{
         return true;
       }
    }

    void dispose(){
      _passController.close();    
     }
}
```

And then insert the following code in another dart file...

```
class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}
class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage>{
   AuthBloc authBloc = new AuthBloc();
   @override
   void dispose(){
     authBloc.dispose();
   }
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context){
     return Scaffold(
       body: Container(
         padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 0, 30, 0),
         constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
         children: <Widget>[
           Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 40, 0, 20),
            child: StreamBuilder(
                stream: authBloc.passStream,
                builder: (context, snapshot) => TextField(
                  controller: _passController,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.black),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      errorText: snapshot.hasError ? snapshot.error:null,
                      labelText: "Password",
                      prefixIcon: Container(
                        width: 50,
                        child: Icon(Icons.lock),
                      ),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xffCED802), width: 1),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(6))
                      )
                  ),
                ),
            )
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 30, 0, 40),
            child: SizedBox(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 52,
              child: RaisedButton(
                onPressed: _onLoginClicked,
                child: Text(
                  "Login",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.white),
                ),
                color: Color(0xff327708),
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(6))
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
         ]
       )
     )
   }
   _onLoginClicked(){
     var isValid = authBloc.isValid(_passController.text);
     if(isValid){
       //insert your action
     }
   }
}
```

I hope it works :)

Comment: Thanks, a new way to do things and organize my code !

Answer (score 2):

**Problem explanation:**

Since you have a **TextFormField** widget inside a **Container** with a *fixed height:40*, whenever you have an error, certain area is required for error message to show up. Hence, the TextFormField height shrinks to adjust both *Input field and Error Message* within the limits of your Container height(40).

**Solution:**

You can just remove the Container *height* parameter. This will wrap your TextFormField height to text size instead

Answer (score 1):

The problem with content padding is that you cant decrease the size of the field to UI requirement with an emphasize on decrease but how ever the second answer helped me come with a solution for my perticular problem, so am sharing that

```
StreamBuilder(
                    stream: viewModel.outEmailError,
                    builder: (context, snap) {
                      return Container(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*.7,
                        height: (snap.hasData)?55:35,
                        child: AccountTextFormField(
                          "E-mail",
                          textInputType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                          focusNode: viewModel.emailFocus,
                          controller: viewModel.emailController,
                          errorText: snap.data,
                          textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.none,
                          onFieldSubmitted: (_) {
                            nextFocus(viewModel.emailFocus,
                                viewModel.passwordFocus, context);
                          },
                        ),
                      );
                    }),
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the above answers. Nothing worked. After a struggle for one day, I could able to achieve it.

To apply custom height to the `TextFormField` without shrinking its height even after the error text, We have to use a **combination** of **constraints**, `contentPadding`, and `isDense`.

```
TextFormField(
  controller: controller,//use your controller
  autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 70, minHeight: 35),
    border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6)),
    contentPadding:const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15, horizontal: 10),
    hintText: hintText,
    isDense: true,
  ),
  validator: validator, //use your custom validator
),
```

I hope it helps. Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

To achieve a fixed height for the TextField while ensuring that the error message does not cause it to decrease in height, you can use a combination of SizedBox and constraints property of TextField.

**Just give the maximum height to sizedbox in my case its 70 and give the minimum height to constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight: 50),**

Like this:

```
SizedBox(
                height: 70,
                width: 240,
                child: TextFormField(
                  autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                  controller: textController,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: false,signed: false),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight: 50),
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 13,horizontal: 18),
                      )
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```