# TextFormField shrinks on error validating FLUTTER

Tags: flutter, dart, validation, textformfield

I am learning Dart/Flutter, and I got a error that I just can't figure it out.

no problem with this textfield:

```
TextFormField(
                keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                controller: emailController,
                obscureText: false,
                focusNode: emailFocusNode,
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  labelText: "Insira o Email",
                  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.mail),
                ),
                validator: (String? value){
                  if (value != null && value.isEmpty){
                    return "Insira o Email";
                  }
                  return null;
                },
              ),
```

but with this one the hight of the Textfield shrinks

```
AnimatedContainer(
                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                height: registerAuthMode ? 65 : 0,
                child: AnimatedOpacity(
                  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                  opacity: registerAuthMode ? 1 : 0,
                  child: TextFormField(
                    validator: (String? value){
                      if(registerAuthMode){
                        if(value != null && value!.isEmpty){
                          return "Insira a Senha";
                        }else{
                          if (value != passwordController.text){
                            return "As senhas não são Iguais";
                          }
                        }
                        return null;
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
                    controller: confirmPasswordController,
                    focusNode: confirmPasswordFocusNode,
                    obscureText: obscureText,
                    textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: "Repita a  Senha",
                        prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.password),
                        suffixIcon: IconButton(
                          onPressed: toggleObscureText, icon: obscureText
                            ? const Icon(Icons.visibility)
                            : const Icon(Icons.visibility_off),)
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

[before validate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Corr5.png)
[after validate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyVCb.png)

the bottom for validate

```
 ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()){
                      }
                    },
                    child: Text(registerAuthMode ? 'Registrar' : 'Entrar'),
                    style: ButtonStyle(
                      elevation: MaterialStateProperty.all(8.0),
                    ),
                  ),
```

my guess is that has some kind of problem with the widget animated container and animated opacity

again, im pretty new to this, so if I did something wrong or ask for help the wrong way sorry.

I can't figure it out. but has to do something with animates opacity and/or AnimatedCointainer

EDIT:

so I checked this :
[Validator error message changes TextFormField's height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56674596/validator-error-message-changes-textformfields-height)

and kinda worked.

I put an error style inside the decoration from the textformfield.

```
decoration: InputDecoration(
                  errorStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 0.1),
```

and this was the result:
[didnt shrink but no error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHVsU.png)

but now de ERROR dosent show anymore. the border turn red, but no more insert your password"or something like this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56674596/validator-error-message-changes-textformfields-height might be this link is helpful to you

Comment: Removing the height of animated container will solve the problem of shrinking here

Comment: @Vaidarbhi kinda worked. I will post the results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing height from animated container will help.

Comment: The thing is.. if I remove the height from animated container there are no more errors.
But in the same screen I have 2 types of textformfields.
The email and password for login, and confirm password and the phone for register. this way when loggin the confirm password gets "invisible". depending on the value of registerAuthMode.

Comment: worked, i had a size box between every textformfield. I remove all of them and set heigh to 90. everything running fine now! thanks